# Trigger Step function based on Snowflake table refresh

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, aws-glue, aws-step-functions

I have a step function which consists of glue jobs,that pulls data from Snowflake database. Is there a way to trigger this step function automatically whenever the snowflake table refreshed? We have a metadata table in Snowflake that tracks the data refresh date and time.

Comment: Is there an REST API for Glue that let's you trigger a job?  If so, you could use scheduled Snowflake `TASK` that checks a `STREAM` to look for changes to a table and then if there is a change to the table, you'd execute an `EXTERNAL FUNCTION` that hits the Glue API to trigger your job.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I just have read only access to the Snowflake DB, which is owned by different team.so creating additional feature on the Snowflake is not that easy. Anything else can we try on AWS side to check the status of refresh and trigger my Step function?